# Building a network at home, what cables to use (if any)?

Tags: networking, home-networking, lan, cable, wireless-networking

My house is currently in ruins and am building it. While doing so, I wanted to design a home network. My main objectives are surfing and HD streaming.

The house is one-level, 100 sq/m (about 300 sq/ft), and one of the rooms is a safety room with Reinforced concrete walls.

About a year ago, when I started planning, I thought about putting Cat 6 STP cables in the walls and create network points in the rooms.

1. Should I use STP or FTP? I heard that STP is a problem regarding connectors and stuff. Is it really beneficial? Will it work OK if I transfer the wire together with the telephone line?
2. Should I maybe go with WLan and count on 802.11n to enable me to stream HD across the house? is 802.11n that good?

Comment: Wired network is more stable than wireless network.Cat 6 STP cables is enough for home users.

Comment: STP is enough? STP is thicker than FTP AFAIK

Comment: Have you considered HomePlug too? The 200mbps one for HD streaming.

Comment: Yep, considered it as well. Heard rumors it doesn't work properly if the entire house is not sitting on the same electric phase

Comment: No harm 'borrowing' a couple and give them a try. No cabling and all those hassle required. Installation is piece of cake too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start by installing some empty conduit, with pull strings in each run. Then, if you need a cable in the future, then you can pull it in.

When the walls are down is the cheapest time to install cables, so it makes sense to take advantage of it, even if you end up using wireless. 3 or 4 runs of fire rated CAT6 STP to each room would give you the most flexibility for the future.

Answer (score 0):

About point 2 I would definitely provide both wired and wi-fi access. Cable is great if you'll need a full speed connection in the future. Wi-fi is great if you have mobile devices such as game consoles or smart phones!